# Pandas DataFrame, Iterate through groups is very slow

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, iterator

I have a dataframe `df` with ~ 300.000 rows and plenty of columns:

```
     | COL_A  |  ... | COL_B  | COL_C  |
-----+--------+-...--+--------+--------+
IDX
-----+--------+-...--+--------+--------+
'AAA'|  'A1'  |  ... |  'B1'  |   0    |
-----+--------+-...--+--------+--------+
'AAB'|  'A1'  |  ... |  'B2'  |   2    |
-----+--------+-...--+--------+--------+
'AAC'|  'A1'  |  ... |  'B3'  |   1    |
-----+--------+-...--+--------+--------+
'AAD'|  'A2'  |  ... |  'B3'  |   0    |
-----+--------+-...--+--------+--------+
```

I need to group after `COL_A` and from each row of each group I need the value of `IDX` (e.G.: 'AAA') and `COL_B` (e.G.: `B1`) in the order given in `COL_C`

For A1 I thus need: `[['AAA','B1'], ['AAC','B3'], ['AAB','B2']]`

This is what I do.

```
grouped_by_A = self.df.groupby(COL_A)
for col_A, group in grouped_by_A:
    group = group.sort_values(by=[COL_C], ascending=True)
    ...
```

It works fine, but it's **horribly slow** (Core i7, 16 GB RAM). It already takes ~ 5 Minutes when I'm not doing anything with the values. Do you know a faster way?

Comment: creating dataframe is a slow process, you could use `group.sort_values(by=[COL_C], ascending=True).values` which generates values quicker but you will deal with a numpy array instead of a dataframe.

Comment: And if you sort before grouping?